# Remover marcador ao adicionar um novo

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override

    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {


        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)).title("New Marker");

        mMap.addMarker(marker);

        System.out.println(point.latitude+"---"+ point.longitude);
    }
});}}
```

no caso esse código adiciona um novo marcador no mapa, mais cada click que eu dou adiciona um novo marcador, então eu quero Remover o marcador antigo ao add um novo

Comment: Novato, voce já tentou `mMap.clear()`

Comment: Novato, posta a solução para ficar registrado, isso ajuda aos próximos que pesquisarem.

Comment: Neste caso não seria melhor criar o marcador uma vez só e mover ao clicar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
            if (marker != null) {
                marker.remove();
            }
            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions());
                    .position(
                            new LatLng(arg0.latitude,
                                    arg0.longitude))
                    .draggable(true).visible(true));
        }
    });}}
```